# How to send logged in status from Express / Passport to a React client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, passport.js

I need to send just a simple boolean value

`let loggedIn = true;`

(that Passport will give me)

from my Express server to my React client.  I would prefer not to embed it in the HTML using a templating engine if there is a better solution.

Seems like this would be common thing to do.

What is the standard way to do this in Express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passport uses http only cookies.  You can change this when you create the session using

```
session(options)
```

Then the cookie will be available on `document.cookies`

Answer (score 0):

You could check on pageload whether a cookie exists that would indicate that the user is logged in. However, if the session has expired or otherwise invalidated after the pageload, you can check this on requests. If a 401 Unauthorized code is returned from the server, then the client will know that the user is not logged in and you can handle this in React.

Answer (score -1):

If you are thinking of react, then forget about rendering in express. You should have an API call to your express API, which returns you an object.

Then in your react codebase react accordingly to the response,

In a redux world, you would trigger the action "USER/SET" with the paylaod from the response. The state would update from the reducer and propagate down to props for all connected components. Makes sense?

Comment: Ok yes. Different path but same goal. Check if there is a cookie somewhere before rendering the page, and if there is, trigger the redux action with its content!

I know im focusing on redux in my solution but you haven been clear in your architecture?

Comment: Ok man, the cookie is not going to get "magically" set. Your express has to send some cookie as in the HTTP Headers section, example: 

    res.append('Set-Cookie', 'titties-size=42');

If some fetch call is receiving this cookie, it should be set automatically in your browser. Then you can use a helper library to ease the access, like [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie).

If this code is executing after the fetch has been resolved, you should be able to acces this:

    const tittySize = Cookie.get('titties') || '38';

Comment: Did you notice the Passport tag.  Passport should set "some sort of" cookied. It might be http header only cookie though.